Check the render method of `PhotoCapturePage`
I am starting out to build an expo project, where I am able to take a photo in the app, but I keep getting an error when I open the tab in expo-go
(https://i.sstatic.net/IYV7fikW.png)
This is the error:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

My code:

import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { router } from 'expo-router';
import * as ExpoCamera from 'expo-camera';

type CameraInstance = ExpoCamera.Camera;

export default function PhotoCapturePage() {
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState<boolean | null>(null);
  const cameraRef = useRef<CameraInstance>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const { status } = await ExpoCamera.Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Permission error:', error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const handleBackPress = () => {
    router.replace("/(tabs)/interests");
  };

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      try {
        // @ts-ignore - we know this method exists
        const photo = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync({
          quality: 0.5,
          base64: true,
          exif: false
        });
        setPhoto(photo.uri);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error taking picture:', error);
      }
    }
  };

  const handleContinue = () => {
    if (photo) {
      console.log('Photo captured:', photo);
    }
  };

  const renderCamera = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
        <ExpoCamera.Camera
          ref={cameraRef}
          style={styles.camera}
          type="front"
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.captureButton} onPress={takePhoto}>
            <View style={styles.captureButtonInner} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  if (hasPermission === null || hasPermission === false) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>We need your permission to show the camera</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.continueButton} 
          onPress={() => ExpoCamera.Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()}
        >
          <Text style={styles.continueButtonText}>Grant Permission</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles.backButton}
          onPress={handleBackPress}
        >
          <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>←</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Time for your close-up!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>One photo in real life is enough? Let's make it count! ✨</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
        {!photo ? renderCamera() : (
          <View style={styles.photoPreview}>
            <Image source={{ uri: photo }} style={styles.photo} />
            <TouchableOpacity 
              style={styles.retakeButton}
              onPress={() => setPhoto(null)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.retakeButtonText}>Retake Photo</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.continueButton, !photo && styles.disabledButton]}
        onPress={handleContinue}
        disabled={!photo}
      >
        <Text style={styles.continueButtonText}>Continue</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 60,
  },
  headerContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  backButton: {
    padding: 10,
  },
  backButtonText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#333',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 40,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 28,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#333',
    marginBottom: 8,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  subtitle: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#666',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  cameraContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 20,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  captureButton: {
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  captureButtonInner: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  photoPreview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  photo: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  retakeButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  retakeButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  continueButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#FF4B6A',
    height: 55,
    borderRadius: 12,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    shadowColor: '#FF4B6A',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  disabledButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#ffb4c4',
  },
  continueButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});````

